# Are Rainbows or related mentioned in Islamic sources?

Tags: quran, hadith, science

I came across [Qur'an 35:27](https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/35/27/default.htm):

> Do not you see that Allah sends down from the sky water, then We bring forth therewith fruits (of) various [their] colors? And in the mountains (are) tracts, white and red (of) various [their] colors, and intensely black.

Is there anything more direct in the Qur'an or Ahadith?

Comment: Why do you ask? This seems to me a totally useless question.

Comment: Interesting Question. Never knew the rainbow is a sign of security from Allah.

Answer (score 3):

There is almost no mention of rainbows in Islamic text, save for two hadiths attributed to Ibn 'Abbas in Al-Adab Al-Mufrad 33/14, with one classified as sahih (authentic) as below, and classified as *da'īf* (weak):

> عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ‏:‏ الْقَوْسُ‏:‏ أَمَانٌ لأَهْلِ الأَرْضِ مِنَ
>   الْغَرَقِ، وَالْمَجَرَّةُ‏:‏ بَابُ السَّمَاءِ الَّذِي تَنْشَقُّ مِنْهُ
>
> Ibn 'Abbas said, "The rainbow is security for the people of the earth
>   that they will not be drowned. The Milky Way is the door of the
>   heavens and forms a furrow through it."
>
> <sub>— [Al-Adab Al-Mufrad 765](https://www.sunnah.com/adab/33/14)</sub>

Comment: @Medi1Saif, you are correct, thanks. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sunnah.com/search/?q=rainbow gives this Saheeh report https://www.sunnah.com/adab/33/14:

> Ibn 'Abbas said, "The rainbow is security for the people of the earth that they will not be drowned. The Milky Way is the door of the heavens and forms a furrow through it."

Also

> **Upon the authority of Ibn Abbaas – Radhiyallahu ‘Anhumaa – who said: “The rainbow is a safeguard for the inhabitants of the earth that they will not be drowned (as a form of destruction as in the time of Nooh**) and the Milky Way is the door of the heavens and the splitting of the heavens will begin from it (i.e on the day of Judgement)”
>
> (Collected by Imaamul Bukhaari in his Adabul Mufrad 767/590)
>
> Shaikh Albaani declared its isnaad ‘**Saheeh**’
>
> https://ah-sp.com/2011/12/08/the-significance-of-the-rainbow-and-the-milky-way/
>   https://maktabasalafiya.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/significance-of-rainbow-and-milky-way.html

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [our] and check our [help]. You should clearly mark your quotes from other sources and give a link to your sources -as you've nicely done-. Note that in this case OP asks for references, else we require answer to be well elaborated, of your own words, focused on answering the actual questions and any claims to be supported by evidences (see [answer]).