# Where can I find the complete sanad for this Hadith that the Milky Way is a doorway to the heavens?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, islamic-philosophy

While going through the below Hadith within this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/are-rainbows-or-related-mentioned-in-islamic-sources):

> Ibn 'Abbas said, "The rainbow is security for the people of the earth
> that they will not be drowned. ***The Milky Way is the door of the
> heavens and forms a furrow through it.***"
>
> [Al-Adab Al-Mufrad 767](https://www.sunnah.com/adab/33/14)

I was unable to understand the second part (highlighted above).

Afaik, a furrow is like a dug out or trench in ground (farms). Does this imply that when the entire universe is taken into consideration,out of the billions upon billions of galaxies, the galaxy of **Milky Way** is special and has a direct entry somewhere within itself to the heavens? ?

Where can I find the ***complete sanad*** for this Hadith?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to the complete sanad as heard and memorized by al-Bukhari is present on the link you gave but only available in Arabic!

> حَدَّثَنَا عَارِمٌ، قَالَ‏:‏ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَوَانَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي بِشْرٍ، عَنْ سَعِيدِ بْنِ جُبَيْرٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ‏

-> 'Arim عَارِمٌ -> Abu 'Awanah أَبُو عَوَانَةَ-> Abu Bishr أَبِي بِشْرٍ -> Sa'id ibn Jubayr -> Ibn 'Abbas ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ‏.

As to the meaning:

> بَابُ السَّمَاءِ الَّذِي تَنْشَقُّ مِنْهُ

can be interpreted in different ways:
One of the literal meanings is get apart of it or split from it.

So the furrow meant is a split, a rill or channel etc.

So it could mean that the Milky Way is only a part of the Universe it could also mean the place or door in the skys where the flooding rain comes from according to Abu a-Sheikh al-Asbahani أبو الشيخ الأصبهاني, based on other narrations of ibn 'Abbas and 'Ali ibn Abi Talib.

> وأخرج ابو الشيخ من طرق عن علي بن أبي طالب قال: )المجرة أبواب السماء التي صب الله منها الماء المنهمر على قوم نوح(.
>   وأخرج ابو الشيخ بسند صحيح عن ابن عباس قال: )المجرة أبواب السماء التي صب الله منها الماء المنهمر على قوم نوح(.
>   وأخرج أبو الشيخ بسند صحيح عن ابن عباس قال: )المجرة باب السماء والذي تنشق منه(.
>   وأخرج من وجوه أخر عن ابن عباس قال: )المجرة باب السماء وطرفها من ههنا مهب الدبور تتيامن وتتياسر(.
>   (source: Imam as-Syuti [Asrar al-Kawn](http://islamport.com/w/akh/Web/248/13.htm))

Comment: Btw can a Hadith be classified as Sahih even though it's sanad doesn't go all the way back to Prophet (SAW)?

Comment: In this case it would be classed as Marfoo3 because even though it stops at the Sahabah, it is implied that the Messenger sallallahu 3alayhi wasallam was the one who originally mentioned this. This is because they are talking about aspects of the unseen (i.e. the connection to the akhira via the Milky Way) and the fact that the water that drowned the people of Nuh came down via the Milky Way.
A good book that discusses marfoo3 is Muqaddimah by Ibn Salah (which is the standard for hadith science). And Allah knows best.

Comment: @Naufal sounds logical, but marfo' AFAIK requires that the Sahabi claimed that the prophet said so.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Baarakallahu Feek. You're right, it has to be attributed to the prophet sallallahu 3alayhi wasallam. Correction: the hadith is mawqoof as it stops at a sahaabi. But because of what is being discussed from an element of the unseen, it will become marfoo3 hukman as no sahabi would know about this except that they heard it from the Messenger sallallahu 3alayhi wasallam. Jazaakallah khayr for your correction.